# Angular 2+ Browser History and Back Button

Tags: angular, html5-history

I have a requirement that the search functions on a component must trigger "history points" so that the user can click the back button in the browser and navigate backwards through different results.  Eventually they also want to be able to navigate away to a separate component (item details)  and still be able to click back and get back to the list of items form their search.  Think of something like searching for orders, filtering by date and status, seeing the list, and then clicking "Order Details".  You would be taken to the order details component and then clicking back would take you back to your filtered list of orders.

The way I understand it, this should be possible through some combination of the `router` and `location`?

I've tried to implement this very simple example that should set a new history point every time a new value is chosen in the select list, but as of yet nothing I have tried is working.

StackBlitx Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vfhwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

**Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location
  ){}
  colors: string[] = ['Red','Green','Blue', 'Purple', 'Black', 'White'];
  selectedColor = this.colors[0];
  selectedColors: string[] = [this.selectedColor];

  selectedColorChanged(event)
  {
    this.selectedColors.push(event.target.value);
    var uniqueValue = this.newGuid();
    //this.router.navigateByUrl("");
    this.location.replaceState("", uniqueValue);
  }

  back(){
    this.location.back();
  }

  newGuid() {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }

}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" (change)="selectedColorChanged($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let c of colors">{{c}}</option>
</select>

<p>
  Selected Color: {{selectedColor}}
</p>

<div>
  Selected Colors:
  <div *ngFor="let c of selectedColors">
    {{c}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using the `RouteReuseStrategy` Here is a tutorial that teaches you how to implement this. https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/how-to-reuse-rendered-component-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy-64628e1ca3eb